# Win10 software for playing random videos from a folder?

Tags: video

A user has a large archive of trip videos. Is there free software that plays randomly videos (clips) from a folder? (something like gPhotoShow)

Answer (score 1):

Get Media Player Classic, drag the folder into its playlist, hit Shuffle.

Comment: The folder has 20 years of photos and videos. Just videos are thousands of files. When I try it, it freezes and crashes.

Comment: last release is in 2017. this answer does not help.